# d3: Existing elements are invisible

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4wrs7g8/7/), I'm trying to append more than one SVG element per data point to the canvas like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   ....
   .append("line")
```

The lines show up in the Firefox inspector, but aren't displayed in the visualization. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting the elements in each other -- you can't do this in SVG. You can only nest elements inside `g` elements, i.e.

```
g
|- circle
|- line
```

You can create this structure by appending `g` elements for the enter selection and keeping a reference to them:

```
var newGs = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
newGs.append("circle")
  ...
newGs.append("line")
  ....
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4wrs7g8/8).

Comment: Thanks! However, I just tried it in my actual code and group elements are only created for some of the data points.. do you have a possible explanation from the top of your head?

Comment: You are probably not matching the elements you want to match. Check what the selection and data contains.

Comment: Indeed.. There were existing `g` elements and your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954604/d3-js-not-using-all-of-the-data-points) gave me the hint to class the new ones. Cheers!